# Content not appearing on Android emulator screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Good Day, I am really new to Android. I am suprised when I run my application just appears blank. This is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="4"
    tools:context="com.example.andani.myapplications2.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtName"
        android:layout_width="122dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="234dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="34dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LblName"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Name"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="34dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LblSurname"
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Surname"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSurname"
        android:layout_width="123dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:text="TextView"

        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="234dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/LblInstitute"
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Institute"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="159dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtInstitute"
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_column="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="233dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="157dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="OnClickSubmit"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="1"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="234dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="231dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnReset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="130dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="231dp" />

</GridLayout>
```

On the design screen the layout appears exactly how I want it. However when I run the application I just get a blank screen. What could I possibly be doing wrong? here is my mainactivity page:

```
package com.example.andani.myapplications2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void OnClickSubmit(View view)
    {
        TextView LblName=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        LblName.getText();


        TextView LblSurname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSurname);


    }
}
```

Another thing I noticed is that my emulator does not launch when I am not connected to the internet. Keeps giving me error:  Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005). Is there a way to run the emulator when it is offlinee. Thank you so much. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.andani.myapplications2">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I checked the event log, I am now thinking the problem has to do with the emulator:

```
18/04/03
5:49 AM Gradle sync started

5:49 AM Project setup started

5:49 AM Gradle sync finished in 17s 396ms (from cached state)

5:52 AM Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug]

5:54 AM Gradle build finished in 1m 54s 721ms

5:55 AM * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

5:55 AM * daemon started successfully

5:55 AM Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

5:56 AM Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error

5:56 AM Emulator: emulator: WARNING: UpdateCheck: Failure: Error

6:02 AM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'Qt event loop'. No response for 15002 ms

6:03 AM Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: Paste your manifest.

Comment: I added the manifest file in

Comment: I tried same in my phone everything works fine.

Comment: Can you just add     android:background="#ff0000" in GridLayout, Just to see if xml is getting loaded correctly. May be it is an issue with emulator. Try it on real device.

Comment: can you navigate to browser or other apps on your emulator?

Comment: I think the problem has to do with the emulator like how all of you are  suggesting.

Comment: It also gives me a cold snapshot boot error.